# Converting PDF to HTML without specialized software

Tags: pdf, conversion, html

Is there a way convert PDF files to HTML without having to use specialized PDF-to-HTML software?

Comment: you mean by 'hand' using notepad?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this can not be answered without more details and TBH does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

No, it would be nearly impossible to do this without any software.

The minimum you would need is a browser however, as you can use one of the many PDF to HTML conversion services online.  Here is one as an example: http://www.convertpdftohtml.net/

Comment: the minimum is `ed` :)

Comment: @akira Actually I was thinking that you could just use pen and paper to write the html, so the real minimum is to not use software as per the question.  However, I suspect the question isn't as absolute as it sounds :)

Comment: i was tempted to give exactly that as an answer as well :)

Comment: So, what you're saying is that renaming the file extension from `.pdf` to `.html` doesn't work? :P

Comment: Welllll, depends on the desktop environment and mime associations.  It doesn't really of course, but if I renamed a pdf to html and tried to open it, it would probably be successfully opened by firefox.  Surely that is conversion enough?  :)

Comment: @iglvzx Oh I just saw you edited the question to be much less silly.  How disappointing.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that using some online website which can help you  to for different conversation here is the link

[Convert](https://www.pdfonline.com/)

and specifically for PDF to HTML

[For PDF To HTML](https://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/)